# How to get max(table1.date1) less than min(table1.date2)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, max

[image]

The table above represents the relevant columns that I am concerned about. I am attempting to add a column indicating the latest `billing_period_end` prior to the first `paid_on` date. This is what I've come up with:

```sql
select 
    owner,
    min(paid_on) as first_paid_on,
    max(case 
        when nullif(billing_period_end > min(paid_on), true) is null OR 0
        then null
        else billing_period_end
    end) as `trial_period_end`
from table group by owner
```

The problem with `max` is that I get `invalid use of group function`. If I remove `max` then the case returns the oldest value: `January 21, 2020, 11:59 PM`.

## Expected result

```
|    owner   |     first_paid_on    |     trial_period_end     |
|============|======================|==========================|
| {owner ID} | May 1, 2020, 5:22 AM | March 31, 2020, 11:59 PM |
```

## Actual result

```
|    owner   |     first_paid_on    |      trial_period_end      |
|============|======================|============================|
| {owner ID} | May 1, 2020, 5:22 AM | January 31, 2020, 11:59 PM |
```

Comment: Please add the expected result to your question. And post your sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the first pay date in a subquery using window functions, then use that information in the outer query:

```
select owner, min_paid_on, 
    max(billing_period_end) as trial_period_end
from (
    select t.*, min(paid_on) over(partition by owner) as min_paid_on
    from mytable t
) t
where billing_period_end < min_paid_on 
group by owner, min_paid_on
```